# How to make use of pyparseface library -- to install?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, pip

I am a mathematician with a slight technological handicap. I am trying to make use of this basic implementation of the open-sourced Google "syntaxnet" library. It is located at https://github.com/plowman/python-mcparseface. I have successfully installed its dependencies tensorflow etc. However I do not know how to make use of this library. I have so far cloned that repository to my computer root path ie: "git clone https://github.com/plowman/python-mcparseface". The repository does not contain a setup.py and therefore I am slightly lost as to what to make of it.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To me it doesn't look like a install able library. Add all of these files into your main project directory. From there you will want to import pyparseface from your main project file.

When you install a python library essentially it is just putting the files into a [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) directory which can then be called from anywhere on your computer. This is not exactly how the install works but it is dependent on your python install directory which should be included in your path (Only if your running windows).